# Hi , i am executing a python script using php but I do not want the page to refresh when a button is clicked because i have embedded other pages too

Tags: php, jquery, python, html, python-2.7

This is the php and html code
   I am using motion to stream video in it

```
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['LightBLINK']))
{
exec("sudo python /var/www/html/open.py");
}

?>

<form method="post">
<button class="btn" name="LightBLINK">Light BLINK</button><br><br></form> 

<body>

<h1>Raspberry Pi Webcameras</h1>
<a href="http://192.168.1.3:8081/">
<img src="http://192.168.1.3:8081/" alt="Camera 1" ></a>
<a href="http://192.168.1.3:8082/">
<img src="http://192.168.1.3:8082/" alt="Camera 2" ></a>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when I click the "LIGH BLINK" button it executes the open.py script but along with it the complete web page refreshes which causes the embedded pages(video in my case) to refresh.

The thing i want is that when i click the "LIGHT BLINK" button it should execute the open.py script as before . but donot refresh the whole page so that my video feed remains undisturbed.

Comment: What is the problem? Which button? What are the results supposed to be?

Comment: Are you looking for an iframe? Maybe you are looking for ajax?

Comment: Question makes very little sense. See [ask]

Comment: @JayBlanchard The problem is that when i press the "Light blink" button whole page reloads that causes the embedded video to reload which is annoying.

Comment: @Huelfe i am new to web programming i have no idea of iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQUERY Ajax

```
    $.post("url to process data",{data:data}, function(response){
       //do something with the response
     )};
```

Comment: Call this in a function after clicking the button

Comment: 1. If you think answer is not full, do not comment after it just edit it. 2. Are you sure that you answer right question as answer is very unclear?

Comment: @DuncanMudulo I am new to web programming can u please explain a bit ?

Comment: Okay, the thing is you need to use ajax, which is just a way of accessing data say from a database, or loading content onto a page without refreshing. Just read a little about JQUERY Ajax, its quite easy. So you will discover that you can attach an onclick event onto the button, such that new data is loaded. its easy @HamzaChaudhary

Comment: @DuncanMudulo your comment helped me a lot . i got it working . THANKU SO MUCH